# How can images be independent of each others size

Tags: html, syntax

I am trying to have images vertically centered, but different sizes on the same page.

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide more information please?

You can use CSS when working with html and use along the lines of the following

```
vertical-align: middle
or
inline-block
```

CSS works on all browsers so alignment of your images would be viewed how you set them on most browsers and platforms. its very difficult to provide the best possible answer when you provide such little information.

failing that you can also wrap them inside a DIV

Please provide as much detail as possible and even provide website links and people on here would be more inclined to help and assist you future.

Thanks